# Activity details unavailable. The activity used in this automation no longer exists. Automation activity error

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, query, automation

[image]
 I Configure Automation with activity query through soap api. When i click 
       query in automation showing Error.****Activity details unavailable. The 
       activity used in this automation no longer exists..****
       How to solve this error .In Below code iam using for creating automation 
       with query.if any modification in this code Please modify the data.

```
     <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Header>
  <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
   <UsernameToken>
              <Username>testuser@123</Username>
              <Password>***********</Password>
   </UsernameToken>
  </Security>
 </Header>
<Body>
   <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options/>
         <Objects xsi:type="Automation">
            <Client>
               <ID>7887554</ID>
            </Client>
            <Name>DataCounting99</Name>
            <CustomerKey>VisitorsCount99</CustomerKey>
            <Description>VisitorsCount2</Description>
           <AutomationTasks>
               <AutomationTask>
                  <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <Name>VisitorsCountingData</Name>
                  <Activities>

                       <Activity>
                        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ObjectID>1223</ObjectID><!-- ObjectID of Query -->
                        <Name>SQL QUERY</Name><!-- Name of Activity -->
                      <ActivityObject xsi:type="QueryDefinition">
                           <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                           <ObjectID>1223</ObjectID><!-- ObjectID of Query -->
                           <CustomerKey>6d5acdb1-934d-4818-bef5-c257baf8b62f</CustomerKey><!-- CustomerKey of Query -->
                           <Name>New_Visitors_Yesterday</Name><!-- Name of Query -->
                           </ActivityObject>
                           </Activity>


                  </Activities>
               </AutomationTask>
            </AutomationTasks>
            <AutomationType>scheduled</AutomationType>
         </Objects>
      </CreateRequest>
 </Body>
  </Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your business unit, under Activities > SQL Queries - do you have an SQL Query already created with the CustomerKey : 6d5acdb1-934d-4818-bef5-c257baf8b62f ?

The error appears to relate to the SQL Activity not existing - either it doesn't exist (deleted?) of you are referencing the incorrect customerkey.

I would check that the activities exist, that the CustomerKeys you are referencing are correct and then try again.

Comment: Hi 
@iManage  I used correct cutomerkey  but iam getting sames error.

Comment: Hi @manage I created automation with query activity but iam not getting existing query in automation. can you know the code about requirement send me.